# Why is typescript complaining that the variable can be undefined when my function checks that it's not undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function component and part of it is a button that gets conditionally enabled.

Simplified:

```
const SomeComponent = ({<lots of props>}: SomeComponentProps) => {
  const isApproveEnabled = (): boolean => {
    return (
      !!someKey1 && // someKey<N> are values from props and are all string | undefined
      !!someKey2 &&
      !!someKey3 &&
      regions.length === 1 &&
      attributes.length === 1
    );
  };

  const onClickApprove = () => {
    if (isApproveEnabled()) {
      callSomeFunction(
        someKey1,
        someKey2,
        someKey3
      )
      .then(res => {
        setApprovalSucceeded(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setApprovalSucceeded(false);
      })
      .finally(() => setApprovalPending(false));
    }
  };

  return (
     <SomeButton
        className="approve-button"
        onClick={onClickApprove}
        disabled={!isApproveEnabled()}
     >
        Approve
     </SomeButton>
  )
}
```

The issue is if I use isApproveEnabled(), I get a Typescript error `TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

However, if I change isApprovedEnabled() to an explicit check:

```
if (someKey1 && someKey2 && someKey3) {
   callSomeFunction(...)
}
```

It will work. However, I would rather not do this because in reality, we just want to use the same criteria as what we use for isApproveEnabled().

Any idea why typescript isn't picking up that I'm already confirming that the values aren't undefined? (I've also changed isApproveEnabled to just use someKey1 && someKey2 && someKey3 instead of the forced boolean casting with !! but it doesn't make any difference)

How can I use isApproveEnabled() here without TypeScript complaining?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/we0gaW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared/unimported types or values.

Comment: +1 for some feedback OP, your question was a bit hard to parse due to the obfuscation in order to "simplify" (and anonymise) the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript isn't that smart. It doesn't 'know' that `someKey1` etc are definitely `string` and not `string | undefined`, because it's not actually analyzing the statements within `isApproveEnabled` to narrow the type of `someKey1`/`someKey2`/`someKey3`. When it comes to calling functions, TypeScript only refers to the return signature for type narrowing; when using an if statement, this is not the case and TypeScript has to evaluate the entire expression for type safety.

TypeScript does have a syntax specifically for this - the `x is T` syntax in the place of the return statement. However, it only works with values that are passed into the function, and you can't specify multiple values. You can sort of cheat around it with an array, though...

```
const isApproveEnabled = (args: (string | undefined)[]): args is string[] => {
  return args.some(a => a  === undefined) === false
}
```

There isn't a way to do what you want to do right now, but I don't feel like that's much of a loss because to me it's also a little hard to read - your function is asserting that invariants are true, and who knows how those invariants might be modified at a later point?

This kind of thing would be particularly hard to prove when it came to asynchronous code!

If you really want to narrow the types, my suggestion would be to have `isApproveEnabled` *return* the sanitised values with the correct typing, rather than asserting that invariants are true.

This would also be a lot easier to read; if what you proposed worked, then after calling a function you'd have to inspect the body of the function to work out *why* the types narrowed, as there's nothing in the type signature of the function to indicate that narrowing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish what you want by using the [aliased conditions and discriminants feature of Typescript 4.4+](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants).

Typescript isn't smart enough to deeply analyze the implementation of a function to understand that it can only be true if the conditions in its return type are true. *But* if you convert the function definition into a simple boolean, TypeScript should be able to infer things better, and you can re-use the value in the render method, and the callback.

```
const isApproveEnabled: boolean = (
   !!someKey1 && // someKey<N> are values from props and are all string | undefined
   !!someKey2 &&
   !!someKey3 &&
   regions.length === 1 &&
   attributes.length === 1
);

if (isApproveEnabled) {
   // TS knows that someKey1, someKey2, etc. are defined
}
```

See [this simplified example in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAOBnZAbwChlk8sBbCAaQgE8BGAfgC5ywpQBzAbmQD0A5ADkskADTIwACwh4UcKClxhgWEHAA2yALTS59ZJWDcZYZCHHIARigAmEGKAj2AdKXJVaDAExsOLhBuYgBfYmIYAFcQBDUNZAAVeTAAYSocDQhwAApCL2o6JikKQr9Q9gxsfABKIk8EDTwLYDwAQRwcbAA3CABRTRstV2QAXmQcutGAPnqyMmUwKKgQZABCNdKfJjIAMl31ze8i309wskaQZuQNVK1gBABrAAk4EHthqDGJqdmSeeQwBgE1aHS6WF6AzgQ1ckzq-wByEu12cUGaABkIGBIF9xlsTm48FEbM0oDlGHUhEl6Dh5AguDgLI1KDgtHBQAQ5MopHYEHAogpAUy3gByCxaLBYR7IOAWWQoS6cLA6GASgDuN2B8sB7U6PX6g2G9kmyGisXiqzAWGQMUcaLAb3sBllQqRbxuIC0Rjs0igURQarkqwARPi-MGdchHM4QK4PADzshE1S3KmwhEzXF1Ktks10iysuBfHkCttGCVjuVKphcHh4Q0mi1deDIYaRuMNmGdsh9ocu6cLo2PXcHi9HdBviaZnN5kCQc39VCYfZ64ikUPURisTjvv3CcTSeTKcJEjS6Qym8gZHBOkYuRAeRA+QKUKC9RCDdCjZG4ORgCz7gnYM2nuOAFCddJ3mAC0I30BQUHMMB8FYIQ1TQtwwDPPB6WARk2WCNwsCgbgBHsLAEDwARr3eGxJUeARlGGMCIF0KxIEozDaWwi9dAAFj4txzEoLQAGJFWwLRdFVLA1V0N5tHoPBWl0LAYDk0DwN0S57Gg7M8Dk95dB07j-1AN4wDwTwyETZNhFTDxQiAA).